# selenium NoSuchElementException C# How to

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using Cookie = OpenQA.Selenium.Cookie;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;

//using System.Web.Script.Serialization;


namespace Walmart
{

   class Programm
   {



        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            amazon();


        }

        private const string V = @"";
        static int a;

        static void amazon()
        {

            List<string> username = new List<string>
            //username // für mehr accounts ein komma und username eingeben
            {"" };
            
            //passwort // genau wie oben 1 ist für 1 oben und unten
            List<string> passwort = new List<string>
            {""};

            //proxis
            List<string> proxy = new List<string>
            {"1234"};

            Random rnd = new Random();

            int r = rnd.Next(username.Count);
            //Gibt aus welchre User mit welchem Password verwendet wird
            Console.WriteLine((string)username[r]);
            Console.WriteLine((string)passwort[r]);

            var ChromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            
            ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Users\emilb\Desktop\PS5 Bot");
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\emilb\Desktop\PS5 Bot", ChromeOptions);

            //öffnet login Seite
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.amazon.de/ap/signin?openid.pape.max_auth_age=900&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.de%2Fgp%2Fyourstore%2Fhome%3Fpath%3D%252Fgp%252Fyourstore%252Fhome%26signIn%3D1%26useRedirectOnSuccess%3D1%26action%3Dsign-out%26ref_%3Dnav_AccountFlyout_signout&openid.assoc_handle=deflex&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0");
            //wartet 1 Sekunde
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            
            //sucht username feld
            IWebElement usernameTextbook = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='email']"));
            //gibt usernamen ein
            usernameTextbook.SendKeys((string)username[r]);
            //Clickt auf Weiter
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='continue']")).Click();

            //wartet 2 Sekunde
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

            //sucht Passwort feld
            IWebElement passwortTextbook = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='password']"));
            //gibt Passwort ein
            passwortTextbook.SendKeys((string)passwort[r]);
            //Clickt auf Weiter
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='signInSubmit']")).Click();

            //wartet 2 Sekunde
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

           
            //sucht Suchbar feld für die PS5 suche
            IWebElement searchbarTextbook = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']"));
            
            //gibt PS5 ein
            searchbarTextbook.SendKeys(("PS5 Konsole"));

            //Drückt in der Suchbar auf suchen
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='nav-search-submit-button']")).Click();

            //wartet 2 Sekunde
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            //Selenium erlaubt jetzt direkt auf die Produktseite der PS5 zu gehen.
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.amazon.de/ECHTPower-Controller-Ladestation-Schnelllade-Playstation/dp/B08PCMKR2C/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=3TEQYT3DCTQ47&keywords=ps5+controller&qid=1655632971&sprefix=ps5+controlle%2Caps%2C131&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&smid=A3OVDQ3MIQE3KN&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExUDBCRTRKRVQwWVVXJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNzA4MDk4M084TllYSEVYS01CSSZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMzExNzM1Mk80RlJBUFNNTURQRyZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=");


            //wartet 1 sekunden
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);


            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='buy-now-button']")).Click();


            WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6));
            w.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@id='turbo-checkout-place-order-button-announce']")).Click());
            
  

        }


    }
```

selenium does not find the last button to press

[buynow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7exv.jpg)

after i press buy now this window opens here

[turbocheckout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66m7a.png)

I have tried all the paths so far, unfortunately that didn't work, as well as ExpectedConditions.

It doesn't seem to work. I don't know if I am giving enough info, so if you need more info of this to help me, please, let me know!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you trying to click on 'turbo-checkout-pyo-button' ?

Comment: @AaronYong yeah...

Comment: Have you tried `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible()` and `By.Id("turbo-checkout-pyo-button")`

Comment: unfortunately does not work either ... @AaronYong